# recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

It was some time ago I studied recurrence relations and I came across this one that I cannot solve:

$a_{n+3}=-3a_{n+2}+4a_{n}$ with $a_{0}=2$ and $a_{1}=-5$

Ansatz: $a_{n}=r^{0}$ then I get

$r^{3}+3r^{2}-4=0$ with roots $r=1$ and $r=-2$ of double multiplicity

so the solution is

$a_{n}=A+B(-2)^{n}+Cn(-2)^{n}$ is this correct?

But I cannot find constants as I have 2 equations with 3 indeterminants...

Comment: You're right, there's an initial condition missing. What is $a_2$?

Comment: that is exactly what I have been wondering....it was not given...but thank you anyway:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you’ve done is correct. There’s no way to pin down $A,B$, and $C$ with the available information: it’s a third-order recurrence, so you need three initial values. The best you can do is solve for $A,B$, and $C$ in terms of the missing value $a_2$.

Comment: maybe author of the problem forgot to give it. Thank you Brian

Comment: @Heidi: That seems very likely. You’re welcome.